# Erro ao buscar dados no banco

Tags: php, mysqli

Quando eu tento fazer uma busca no BD para um login, ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be
>   converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\TCC\index.php on line 66

Preciso passar todos esses valores do resultado para a outra página.

```
if (isset($_POST['entrar']) && $_POST['entrar'] == "login"){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];

        if(empty($email) || empty($senha)){
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript"> alert ('preencha todos os campos');
            </script>
            <?php
        }else{
                $query = "SELECT id,nome, adm, email, senha, rua_num, bairro, tel FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha' ";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
                $busca = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


            if($busca > 0){
                $_SESSION['id'] = $linha['id'];
                $_SESSION['nome'] = $linha['nome'];
                $_SESSION['rua_num'] = $linha['rua_num'];
                $_SESSION['bairro'] = $linha['bairro'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $linha['email'];
                $_SESSION['tel'] = $linha['tel'];
                $_SESSION['senha'] = $linha['senha'];
            echo "$result";
                //header('location: logado.php');
                //echo "$email - $senha - $nome";



                //exit;
            }else{
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript"> alert('usuario ou senha incorretos!');</script>
                <?php
            }
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está devolvendo a variável `$result` como string. No seu cód tá assim:

```
 if($busca > 0){
            $_SESSION['id'] = $linha['id'];
            $_SESSION['nome'] = $linha['nome'];
            $_SESSION['rua_num'] = $linha['rua_num'];
            $_SESSION['bairro'] = $linha['bairro'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $linha['email'];
            $_SESSION['tel'] = $linha['tel'];
            $_SESSION['senha'] = $linha['senha'];
        echo "$result"; <-- o erro tá aqui
```

Você tem que fazer assim:

```
 if($busca > 0){
            $_SESSION['id'] = $linha['id'];
            $_SESSION['nome'] = $linha['nome'];
            $_SESSION['rua_num'] = $linha['rua_num'];
            $_SESSION['bairro'] = $linha['bairro'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $linha['email'];
            $_SESSION['tel'] = $linha['tel'];
            $_SESSION['senha'] = $linha['senha'];
        echo $result;
```

Comment: ele da o mesmo erro se eu der um echo no $busca ele retorna 1, mas nao consigo passar os dados para a outra pagina.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query()` retorna um recurso de objeto para a variável `$result`, não uma **string**.

Logo deve fazer um `loop`

```
while ($linha = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $linha['id'];
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $linha['nome'];
    $_SESSION['rua_num'] = $linha['rua_num'];
    $_SESSION['bairro'] = $linha['bairro'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $linha['email'];
    $_SESSION['tel'] = $linha['tel'];
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $linha['senha'];
}
```

Comment: entendi, mas adicionei o while podem nao printa nada na tela

Comment: @caio perdão, altere dentro do `while`, `echo $result` para `echo $linha` ou `echo $linha['nome']` etc.

Comment: Na verdade a variável `$linha` é um `array` então para printa todos os dados contido nela deve usar `print_r($linha)`

Comment: continua sem retornar nada, ja tem um mysqli_fetch_assoc dentro do else será que é por isso?

Comment: Possivelmente .

Comment: necessito do resultado dessa query para fazer o login e passar os dados do usuario para a outra pagina (logado.php) tem um jeito mais facil de buscar esses dados, fazer o login e ainda passar para a outra pagina? queria passar todos de uma vez para nao fazer outra query na outra pagina.

Comment: Você está fazendo isso já, e salvando em uma `sessão`, se os dados estão corretos, então os dados estão sendo salvos na `sessão`, para resgatar os dados na pagina `logado.php` de um `echo $_SESSION['nome']`

Comment: consegui, retirei o outro fetch_assoc de cima, obrigado!